Django haystack with xapian backend: filtering for empty MultiValueField
I have an Index with this field:
tags=indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)

def prepare_tags(self, obj):
    return obj.data.get('tags', [])

How do I use SearchQuerySet to filter for empty tags?
Nething of what I've tried works:
events=SearchQuerySet().models(Event)
events.filter(tags=[])
events.filter(tags='')
events.filter(tags=None) # Silly
events.filter(tags__in=[]) # Weird

While there are entries with empty tags:
(pdb) ev1=[_ for _ in events if not _.object.data.get('tags', [])]
(pdb) len(ev1)
922

Or even on the haystack level:
(pdb) len([_ for _ in events if not _.tags])
922

